# Able to hit Jenkins service on localhost:8080, unable to hit Jenkins service remotely - macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Tags: jenkins, networking, macos-high-sierra

As mentioned in the title, I have a Jenkins service running on port 8080. And I am able to use Jenkins just fine when I'm on localhost:8080 within the machines browser.

The problem I am facing is when I attempt to hit the Jenkins over the network. A few strange things I noticed:

1.) Over the network, I am able to ssh and VNC into machine just fine. (As mentioned in netstat)

2.) When I run the netstat command on the machine, I see VNC SSH listening. But not Jenkins on port 8080 listening.

How would I get Jenkins to appear to be listening on port 8080 within netstat? I've checked the system firewall, it's turned off. And checked network firewall rules, no interference there.

What else could be the culprit?

```
 netstat -ap tcp | grep -i "listen"
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp46      0      0  *.http-alt             *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp46      0      0  *.49341                *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp46      0      0  *.49336                *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.9085         *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.49266                *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.49266                *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp46      0      0  *.18170                *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.62722        *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  localhost.commplex-lin *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.commplex-lin *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.60014        *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp46      0      0  *.camp                 *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.camp                 *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp46      0      0  *.sunproxyadmin        *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.29754        *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.1023         *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.kerberos             *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.kerberos             *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.bhmds                *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.sco-sysmgr           *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.sco-sysmgr           *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.ms-wbt-server        *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.ms-wbt-server        *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.afpovertcp           *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.afpovertcp           *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  localhost.intu-ec-clie *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  localhost.intu-ec-clie *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.microsoft-ds         *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.microsoft-ds         *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.dec_dlm              *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.dec_dlm              *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.eppc                 *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.eppc                 *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp4       0      0  *.ssh                  *.*                    LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0  *.ssh                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was tricky to figure out. Turned out that it was a third party firewall that blocked communication with the services!

The way I debugged it is I spun up a VM, downloaded stock mac-os high serria from developer.apple.com and ran that. Within minutes, I was able to hit the service I started on the VM just fine.